# Metabox nonce not allowing update

Tags: custom-field, nonce

I'm having a problem correcting saving metabox data on a custom post type. I thought I fixed it by applying the advice on this post: [Metabox nonce PHP notice](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/47791/metabox-nonce-php-notice)

which does get rid of the warning but leaves me unable to update the metaboxes. Here is the code in question :

```
function save_goal_info_meta( $post_id ) {
    global $goal_info_meta_fields;

    // verify nonce
    if ( ! isset( $_POST['product_noncename'] ) || ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['goal_info_meta_box_nonce'], basename( __file__ ) ) ) {
        return $post_id;
    }

    // check autosave
    if ( defined( 'DOING_AUTOSAVE' ) && DOING_AUTOSAVE ) {
        return $post_id;
    }

    // check permissions
    if ( 'page' == $_POST['post_type'] ) {
        if ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_page', $post_id ) )
            return $post_id;
    } elseif ( ! current_user_can( 'edit_post', $post_id ) ) {
        return $post_id;
    }

    // loop through fields and save the data
    foreach ( $goal_info_meta_fields as $field ) {
        if ( $field['type'] == 'tax_select' )
            continue;

        $old = get_post_meta( $post_id, $field['id'], true );
        $new = $_POST[$field['id']];

        if ( isset( $new ) && ! empty( $new ) && ( $new != $old ) ) {
            update_post_meta( $post_id, $field['id'], $new );
        } elseif ( '' == $new && $old ) {
            delete_post_meta( $post_id, $field['id'], $old );
        }
    }
}

add_action( 'save_post', 'save_goal_info_meta' );
```

I understand more or less why it isn't updating but I can't seem to fix it without having an "Undefined Index".

```
$goal_info_meta_fields = array(

   array(
    'label' => 'Home Goals by:',
    'desc' => 'Add and select home scorers',
    'id' => $prefix.'home-scorers',
    'type' => 'home_player_list'
   ),
   array(
    'label' => 'Away Goals by:',
    'desc' => 'Add and select away scorers',
    'id' => $prefix.'away-scorers',
    'type' => 'away_player_list'
   )
);
```

Here is the output :

```
function show_goal_info_meta_box($field, $meta, $items = null) {
    global $goal_info_meta_fields, $post;
// Use nonce for verification

echo '<input type="hidden" name="goal_info_meta_box_nonce" value="'.wp_create_nonce(basename(__FILE__)).'" />';

// Begin the field table and loop
echo '<table class="admin-table">';
foreach ($goal_info_meta_fields as $field) {
    // get value of this field if it exists for this post
    $meta = get_post_meta($post->ID, $field['id'], true);
    // begin a table row with
    echo '<tr>
            <th><label for="'.$field['id'].'">'.$field['label'].'</label></th>
            <td>';
    switch($field['type']) {


        // home_player_list
    case 'home_player_list':
        echo '<a class="repeatable-add button" href="#">+</a> <span class="description">'.$field['desc'].'</span>
            <ul id="'.$field['id'].'-repeatable" class="custom_repeatable">';
        $post_id = get_the_ID();
        $team_id = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'report_home-select');

        $items = get_users( array (
                'meta_key' => 'team-meta',
                'meta_value' => $team_id
            ));
        $i = 0;

        if ($meta) {
            foreach($meta as $row) {

                echo '<li><span class="sort hndle button">|||</span>';
                echo '<select name="'.$field['id'].'['.$i.']" style="width:200px;" id="report_home-scorers">
                <option value="">Select One</option>'; // Select One
                foreach($items as $item) {
                    echo '<option value="'.$item->ID.'"',$row == $item->ID ? ' selected="selected"' : '','>'.$item->display_name.'</option>';
                }
                echo '</select><a class="repeatable-remove button" href="#">-</a></li>';

                $i++;
            }
        } else {
            echo '<li><span class="sort hndle button">|||</span>';
            echo '<select name="report_home-scorers[0]" style="width:200px;" id="'.$field['id'].'">
            <option value="NULL">Select One</option>'; // Select One

            foreach ($items as $item) {
                echo '<option value="" selected="selected">'.$item->display_name.'</option>';
            }

            echo '</select><a class="repeatable-remove button" href="#">-</a></li>';

        }
        echo '</ul>';
        break;

        // away_player_list
    case 'away_player_list':
        echo '<a class="repeatable-add button" href="#">+</a> <span class="description">'.$field['desc'].'</span>
            <ul id="'.$field['id'].'-repeatable" class="custom_repeatable">';
        $postid = get_the_ID();
        $team_id = get_post_meta( $postid, 'report_away-select');

        $items = get_users( array (
                'meta_key' => 'team-meta',
                'meta_value' => $team_id
            ));


        $i = 0;
        if ($meta) {
            foreach($meta as $row) {
                echo '<li><span class="sort hndle button">|||</span>';
                echo '<select name="'.$field['id'].'['.$i.']" class="chzn-select" style="width:200px;" id="'.$field['id'].'" value="'.$row.'">
                <option value="">Select One</option>'; // Select One
                foreach($items as $item) {
                    echo '<option value="'.$item->ID.'"',$row == $item->ID ? ' selected="selected"' : '','>'.$item->display_name.'</option>';
                }
                echo '</select><a class="repeatable-remove button" href="#">-</a></li>';

                $i++;
            }
        } else {
            echo '<li><span class="sort hndle button">|||</span>';
            echo '<select name="'.$field['id'].'['.$i.']" class="chzn-select" style="width:200px;" id="'.$field['id'].'">
            <option value="">Select One</option>'; // Select One

            foreach ($items as $item) {
                echo '<option value="" selected="selected">'.$item->display_name.'</option>';
            }

            echo '</select><a class="repeatable-remove button" href="#">-</a></li>';

        }
        echo '</ul>';
        break;

    } //end switch
    echo '</td></tr>';
} // end foreach
echo '</table>'; // end table
}
```

Comment: What's the value of `$goal_info_meta_fields`?

Comment: I added it below.

Comment: Can you also post the code you're using to output the nonce field, i.e. the `wp_nonce_field()` bit.

Comment: There you are. It's a bit long...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was that you should have changed `product_noncename` to `goal_info_meta_box_nonce`. I've also made a few other changes, commenting out the old lines for comparison, which should avoid any further errors (including the undefined index).

```
// verify nonce
// if ( ! isset( $_POST['product_noncename'] ) || ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['goal_info_meta_box_nonce'], basename( __file__ ) ) ) {
if ( ! isset( $_POST['goal_info_meta_box_nonce'] ) || ! wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['goal_info_meta_box_nonce'], basename( __file__ ) ) ) {
    return $post_id;
}

...

// loop through fields and save the data
foreach ( $goal_info_meta_fields as $field ) {
    // if ( $field['type'] == 'tax_select' )
    if ( $field['type'] == 'tax_select' || ! isset( $_POST[ $field['id'] ] ) )
        continue;

    $old = get_post_meta( $post_id, $field['id'], true );
    $new = $_POST[ $field['id'] ];

    // if ( isset( $new ) && ! empty( $new ) && ( $new != $old ) ) {
    if ( ! empty( $new ) && $new != $old ) {
        update_post_meta( $post_id, $field['id'], $new );
    } elseif ( '' == $new && $old ) {
        delete_post_meta( $post_id, $field['id'], $old );
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh how awful! I can't believe I didn't catch that! Thank you for pointing it out. You've saved me another few hours of tearing my hair out. I copied and pasted from another response to a similar question.